# Craft Commerce Categories and Product Types

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, categories

I've just started using craft Commerce. What's the accepted way to categorise products? For example, i’m trying to replicate this structure:

- Bags and Scarves (shows all products in this category)

  - Hand Bags (shows just hand bags)
  - Overnight Bags (shows just overnight)
  - Purses (shows just purses)
  - Scarfs (shows just scarfs)
- Hair Accessories (shows all accessories)

  - Hair Bands (shows just hair bands)
  - Hair Clips (etc)
  - Brushes (etc)
  - Combs (etc)
- Hair Care Products (shows all hair care ‘HERO’ products)

  - Product with variations
  - Product with variations
  - Product with variations
  - Product with variations
  - etc
  - etc
- Jewellery  (all jewellery, no sub cats)
- Gift Vouchers

  - £10
  - £20

I can’t see how product types would work?  I added the top level as if they were “departments” but the front end doesn’t show these?

Any help and code examples appreciated to get me going.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Product Types are really for the content of the fields and field layout of each product plus basic options for things like tax/shipping category defaults.

For full categorization in menus and site structure, we recommend putting a category field on all products.

For example you might have a category field names 'department' which you put all products into.

You then could show all products related to that category: https://craftcms.com/support/entries-related-to-category

Let me know if you need more guidance in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Luke, with some experimenting and reading around I decided to try the categorisation option.  At the moment i'm putting ALL bags and scarves into a Product Type called "Bags and Scarves" but the Variations are confusing because a bag and a scarf clearly don't have any similarities! :(  I haven't got as far as templating yet.

Comment: Just thought... I should create a 'Type' each for scarves and bags and use the categories to do the sorting.  I'll stop thinking out loud now...