# Craft CMS Product Types

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am trying to setup some products in my test website. I am unsure how I should go about creating the products. Should each product category be created as a product type?

An example is, if I have some art, how should I construct the products?

Imagine if I have these different "things" on the shop:

- Prints
- Paintings
- Illustrations
- Something
- Something Else

I tried to create a different product type for each but then I ran into issues because I needed a template for each product type. Also I couldn't view the archive page.

Should I create an "Art" product type and work out a way to display these? Or just create each as individual product types?

I am also confused about templating with archive/entry pages. Say if I have  `templates/shop/art/_entry.twig` does craft automatically know that the archive template should be in the same directory?

Answer (score 2):

Answered at https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/22468/7356

"Product Types are really for the content of the fields and field layout of each product plus basic options for things like tax/shipping category defaults.

For full categorization in menus and site structure, we recommend putting a category field on all products."

Comment: PS. Not sure what you mean by "archive" templates, but probably best tackled in another question.

Comment: Thanks, that put me in the right direction

Comment: You're welcome @Callum - I went down exactly the same (wrong) direction with my first Commerce project 